# Не происходит подключение к VPN

Tags: linux, debian, vpn

Linux Debian 10, добавил впн из freevpn.me из файла в networkManager. Подклоючение создалось, но при нажатие на "Подключится" ничего не происходит. Система чистая, только что установленная. На ноутбуке с виндой и на двух андроидах работает, а тут даже не подключается, даже не пытается. Может подскажите где какой лог лежит? Или куда копать?

Comment: [Пакет](https://packages.debian.org/ru/source/buster/network-manager-openvpn) для NM установлен?

Comment: @AndreyMihalev Неужели все так просто))) Да, начал подключатся, но не работает. Думаю тут я уже разберусь. А еще, не подскажите где логи смотреть?

Comment: `journalctl -u NetworkManager` например

Comment: @Andrey Mihalev спасибо вам большое

Comment: Ну так чё? В чем проблема-то была?

Comment: @don Rumata пакет поставил, начал подключаться но не подключается))) сейчас чуть другим занят.